# How to group mysql query results based on a avg calculation?

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I'm trying to show my post's comments based on how good their AVG (positive votes - negatives votes) are... but I'm getting confusing while trying to build the query to do that. I need them to be displayed like: the best AVG at the beginning untill the worst AVG at the end, Like in a descendent way.

here is the query I'm using to do it:

```
SELECT c.user AS user, DATE_FORMAT(c.date,'%d de %b a las %h:%i %p') AS datee, c.comment AS comment, COUNT(DISTINCT l.id_like) AS likes, COUNT(DISTINCT d.id_dislike) AS dislikes, AVG(likes - dislikes) AS avg  FROM comments c LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.id_comment=c.id_comment LEFT JOIN dislikes d ON c.id_comment=d.id_comment  WHERE c.id_post= ? AND l.id_like > 0 GROUP BY c.id_comment DESC LIMIT 10
```

but is not working as I would like to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would help if thought of the calculation as the *difference* rather than the *average*:

```
SELECT c.user AS user,
       DATE_FORMAT(c.date,'%d de %b a las %h:%i %p') AS datee,
       c.comment AS comment,
       COUNT(DISTINCT l.id_like) AS likes,
       COUNT(DISTINCT d.id_dislike) AS dislikes,
       (COUNT(DISTINCT l.id_like) - COUNT(DISTINCT d.id_dislike)) as Difference
FROM comments c LEFT JOIN
     likes l
     ON l.id_comment = c.id_comment LEFT JOIN
     dislikes d
     ON c.id_comment = d.id_comment 
WHERE c.id_post= ? AND l.id_like > 0
GROUP BY c.user, datee, c.id_comment DESC
ORDER BY Difference DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: that's what I'm talking about! it worked like a charm, thanks dude :P